# gcc 4.7 Give me error message

Tags: c++, gcc

I have Debian 6.04 , and the latest gcc version included is gcc 4.4 , and this version doesn't support C++11 , and i look for another version support C++11 ( some features not completely supported ) , so i follow this [Page](http://nosemaj.org/debian-gcc-4-7)

I suggest to install it and My NetBeans IDE succeeded to find gcc 4.7 andlink it , but when i compile the code using a test by using std::unique_ptr i get this error message :

***This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.***

i found the error source and her is :

**bits/c++0x_warning.h**

```
#ifndef _CXX0X_WARNING_H
#define _CXX0X_WARNING_H 1

#ifndef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: I know it sounds crazy, but have you tried adding the `-std=c++11' option to the command-line ?

Comment: I added a link to my answer where they are showing the build options. See if it helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why random header not importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237259/why-random-header-not-importing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all. Trying adding `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` to the compiler options in your NetBeans IDE.

I've not used Netbeans but see this [link](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-95374.html) where a snapshot of build variables is shown and that is where you need to add the compiler options.

Comment: i add -std=c++1 to my netbeans mut i still have the problem