# random header when added in c++ programme not working

Tags: c++, gcc, random, ubuntu-14.04, gcc-warning

While compiling the above code 
this is the error which i am getting.

```
 #include <random>
 #include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,6);
  int dice_roll = distribution(generator);  // generates number in the range 1..6   
}
```

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/random:35:0,
                 from fv.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

My gcc version is g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Please help me

Comment: Try compiling with the flag `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Did you do what the error message says?

Comment: Did you try what the error message told you to do, adding `-std=c++11` to the compiler's command-line options?

Comment: If the above mentioned flag -std=c++11 doesn't work on compilation, try -std=c++0x.

Comment: @Ganesh Delli Are you using an IDE to develop with?  Make?  CMake?

Comment: @laser_wizard gcc 4.8 supports -std=c++11

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling C++11 with g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363646/compiling-c11-with-g) or [c++ - gcc 4.7 Give me error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108328/gcc-4-7-give-me-error-message)

Comment: I just pasted the error message in the question itself In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/random:35:0, from fv.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why random header not importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237259/why-random-header-not-importing)

Answer (score 3):

This will compile fine after adding the `-std=c++11` flag to your compilation command. This flag is needed to make `gcc` support `c++11` features such as `<random>`.

If you compile in an terminal, just add the flag somewhere. If you use an IDE, you might have to change some option, but that does (of course) depend on your specific IDE.